using flutter_native_splash but still seeing flutter logo
I'm having issues figuring out how to get flutter_native_splash to work. I want to add my own custom splash screen but before I can do that I need the flutter logo to stop showing.
pubspec.yaml
name: vta_customer_mobile
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: "none" # This prevents accidental publishing

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0" # Ensure compatibility with your current Flutter SDK

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2: ^3.6.5
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.1
  http: ^1.2.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  provider: ^6.0.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/white_logo.png

native_splash.yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false

  color: "#d4e4ed"

I ran  dart run flutter_native_splash:create --path=native_splash.yaml
Building package executable... 

Built flutter_native_splash:create.

[Android] Updating launch background(s) with splash image path...

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml

[Android] Updating styles...

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/styles.xml

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml

[iOS] Updating ios/Runner/Info.plist for status bar hidden/visible

✅ Native splash complete.

Now go finish building something awesome!  You rock! 

Like the package? Please give it a  here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

it's in same directory as pubspec.yaml. when I run flutter clean, flutter pub get and then flutter run I still see this

How can I make this go away and use a flutter_native_splash. What am I missing? I appreciate any help!

I think you used app in android-12. but you misses it's config. Try this options
